# LDAP connectivity not working on server IIS but working in my local VS 2015

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

Below is the code where I try to connect to LDAP by VB.NET code. The below code works on my local PC in VS 2015 but is giving an error when i host the same code in the server.

Is there something wrong with the way I call the FindAll() function. This same function returns me the required value in my local PC but gives an exception in the server. I have captured the exception from the server and pasted the error message below after the code

```
Private entry As DirectoryEntry = Nothing

Public Enum ADProperties
    distinguishedName
    displayName
    telephoneNumber
    samAccountName
    manager
    title
    department
    givenName
    sn
End Enum

entry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=asia,DC=contoso,DC=com" )

Dim lstSearch As List(Of LDAPSearchResult) = New List(Of LDAPSearchResult)

lstSearch = Search(ADProperties.samAccountName, parts(1).ToString())

                If Not lstSearch Is Nothing AndAlso lstSearch.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each a As LDAPSearchResult In lstSearch
                        email = a.UserPrincipalName
                        userid = a.ComputerUserId
                        name = a.GivenName
                        Exit For
                    Next

Public Function Search([property] As ADProperties, propertyValue As [String]) As List(Of LDAPSearchResult)
    Dim lstSearchResults As New List(Of LDAPSearchResult)()

    Try
        Dim search__1 As New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        Dim resultCollection As SearchResultCollection


        LoadProperties(search__1)

        search__1.Filter = String.Concat("(", [property].ToString(), "=", propertyValue, ")")

        resultCollection = search__1.FindAll() //Exception is caught here

        If resultCollection IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each result As SearchResult In resultCollection
                Dim objSearchResult As New LDAPSearchResult()

                MapToObject(result, objSearchResult)

                lstSearchResults.Add(objSearchResult)
            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try

    Return lstSearchResults
End Function

Private Sub MapToObject(result As SearchResult, ByRef objSearchResult As LDAPSearchResult)
    Try

        If result.Properties("title").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.Title = result.Properties("title")(0).ToString()
        End If
        If result.Properties("distinguishedName").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.distinguishedName = result.Properties("distinguishedName")(0).ToString()
        End If
        If result.Properties("displayName").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.displayName = result.Properties("displayname")(0).ToString()
        End If
        If result.Properties("telephoneNumber").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.telephoneNumber = result.Properties("telephoneNumber")(0).ToString()
        End If
        If result.Properties("samAccountName").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.samAccountName = result.Properties("samAccountName")(0).ToString()
        End If

        If result.Properties("department").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.department = result.Properties("department")(0).ToString()
        End If
        If result.Properties("givenName").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.FirstName = result.Properties("givenName")(0).ToString()
        End If
        If result.Properties("sn").Count > 0 Then
            objSearchResult.LastName = result.Properties("sn")(0).ToString()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ex.Message.ToString()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Error says as below

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
```

Please help

Comment: Show the complete exception.

Comment: Below is the complete exception

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at .Search(ADProperties property, String propertyValue)]

Comment: You're missing the exception's message body! Please add the first line to your code - the one which you're showing is the exception stack trace without exception message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding the below code in the web.config

```
<identity impersonate="false">
```